# why form_for does not work for me

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

(ruby 1.9.2 rails 3.0.6)

I am new to ROR, sorry for my simple question.

I have a form and a controller, when i launch my app, i can see the log have been displayed.. however there are exception when rendering the view...

Everything should look just fine.. what is the problem? how can I fix it?

Thanks.

```
undefined method `users_path' for #<#<Class:0x47c7678>:0x47c6118>
Extracted source (around line #2):

1: <h1>Welcome Aboard</h1>
2: <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
3:   <table>
4:     <tr>
5:       <td><%= f.label :username %></td>

class RegisterController < ApplicationController

  def sign_up
    logger.debug("sign_up inoked")

    @user = User.new

    logger.debug("sign_up finished")
  end

end
```

views/register/sign_up.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :username %></td>
      <td><%= f.text_field :username %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :password %></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><%= f.label :password_confirmation %></td>
      <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that you do not have the appropriate routes. Do you have a line like :

```
resources :users
```

in your routes.rb file ? If not try adding that please. Or just create the particular users_path named route.

Comment: after adding resources:users. it is working now. 

but why i need to add my model into route???

Comment: form_for is looking for resource_path by default (@users in your case), so users_path. It's the RESTful way. This route was not existent and you were getting an error. If you want to specify another route, you can use "form_for @user, :url => your_custom_path", but it has to be something.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little confusing when you think rails is JUST model, view controller...but a route is also required for things to work.  I guess "Model, View, Route, Controller" just doesn't slip of the tongue as easily.